# Where am I going wrong with this code?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-computercraft

FTB Direwolf20 v 1.0.21 CC 1.57

I have a turtle mining script that I am getting an error 'attempt to call nil' on line 18:

```
if turtle.getFuelLevel() >= turtle.getFuelLimit() - 500 then
```

and cannot see what's causing it. Here's the complete code:

```
chestFuel = 15
fuel = 14

function CheckFuel()
if turtle.getFuelLevel() ~= 'unlimited' then
 if turtle.getItemCount(fuel) == 0 then
  turtle.select(chestFuel)
  turtle.placeUp()
  turtle.select(fuel)
  turtle.suckUp()
  turtle.digUp()
  turtle.select(1)
  end
  if turtle.getFuelLevel() < 200 then
   print('Current fuel lvl: ' .. turtle.getFuelLevel() .. ': Refueling...')
   turtle.select(fuel)
   while true do
    if turtle.getFuelLevel() >= turtle.getFuelLimit() - 500 then
     print('Fueled Up')
     break
    end
    turtle.refuel()
    print('Fuel lvl: ' .. turtle.getFuelLevel())
   end
   turtle.select(1)
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Relevant meta - http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7661/is-programming-in-a-game-on-topic-here

Comment: Hve you declared the fonction getFuelLimit ? What does it look like ?

Comment: @wizliz getFuelLimit is a function in the turtle api.

Comment: You will have a better shot at an answer actually helping you solve this problem on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at the [Turtle API](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Turtle_(API)) you will see the `getFuelLimit()` is only implemented in version 1.6, and you are running version 1.57.

[From the wiki:](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Turtle.getFuelLimit)

> Added by version 1.6 of ComputerCraft, this command returns the maximum amount of fuel a turtle may store. By default, a regular turtle may hold 20,000 units, and an advanced model 100,000 units; both values can be changed in ComputerCraft.cfg.
>
> In builds prior to 1.6, turtles may store practically unlimited amounts of fuel.

Answer (score 6):

to make it forward compatible you can do the following:

```
function getFuelLimit()
    if turtle.getFuelLimit ~= nil then
        return turtle.getFuelLimit()
    else
        return 0;
    end
end
```

and add a check for 0 when checking the fuel against it or set your own fuel limit